# RSA Decryption guidance

Tags: cryptography, rsa

This is an exercise, where the objective is to
decrypt the cipher c to recover the unknown "flag" given p, q, n, e, and c and given that they were generated from the following code by the exercise creator:

```py
from Crypto.Util.number import getPrime, bytes_to_long
p = getPrime(512)
q = getPrime(512)
n = p * q
e = 88 # miles per hour required
c = pow(flag, e, n)
```

I have been unable to make any progress.

Comment: You can't have a `e` value of 88.

Comment: i have been provided with value of 88 as it then implies is not standard rsa so wondering how to solve it when e is not co prime

Comment: I think I know but I'll have to do some thinking to be sure

Answer (score 1):

Again, this is rather tricky, especially for those who aren't conversant in elementary number theory. There is a public key cryptosystem related to RSA called the [Rabin cryptosystem.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin_cryptosystem) It uses 2 as a public exponent. However, if you have *any* even exponent the decryption problem reduces to first decrypting using the Rabin theory and then pretending you are back in an RSA cryptosystem and decrypting using RSA theory (you could do RSA first and then do Rabin, the order doesn't matter). In your case your public exponent is *e* = 88 = 11 * 8. Thus *c* = *flag*<sup>88</sup> = (*flag*<sup>11</sup>)<sup>8</sup> mod n. So you must first take 3 square roots, i.e. an eighth root mod n, and then raise this eighth root to the *d*-th power, where d = 11<sup>-1</sup> mod Φ(n).

This seems straightforward, but consider the following points and difficulties:

- You must compute square roots mod p and mod q separately
- Each square root computation may produce 0 or 2 square roots except for the first one, which is guaranteed to produce 2.
- Since you are taking square roots three times in succession for all the square roots found at the previous iteration, you may end up with as many as 8 8th roots or as few as 2 (I think, I'll have to double check that). Now these 8th roots are mod p and mod q, but you need them mod n. For that you need to use the [Chinese Remainder Theorem or CRT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem). If there are *A* 8th roots mod p and *B* 8th roots mod q then you will have (*A* * *B*) 8th roots mod n. Only one of these is correct. In practice with moduli this large, the wrong answers will all fail to decode using the utf-8 decode because they will just end up as sequences of 128 random bytes.

I have actually performed these steps and decrypted the flag, so I know it works.

Here are a couple of python functions that take advantage of the [`sympy` module](https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html) to compute square roots mod a prime and to compute the CRT.

```py
import itertools
from typing import Iterable

from sympy import sqrt_mod
from sympy.ntheory.modular import crt

def eighth_roots_mod(x: int, p: int) -> list[int]:
    sqrt_list = [x]
    for _ in range(3):
        sqrt_list = [sqrt_mod(z, p, all_roots=True) for z in sqrt_list]
        sqrt_list = [root for roots in sqrt_list for root in roots]
    return sqrt_list


def decrypt(rsa_params: Iterable):
    n, p, q, e, c = rsa_params
    eighth_roots_p, eighth_roots_q = eighth_roots_mod(c, p), eighth_roots_mod(c, q)
    eighth_roots_mod_n = [int(crt((p, q), (root_8_p, root_8_q))[0]) for root_8_p, root_8_q in
                          itertools.product(eighth_roots_p, eighth_roots_q)]
    phi = (p - 1) * (q - 1)
    d = pow(11, -1, phi)
    plain_candidates = [pow(root_8, d, n) for root_8 in eighth_roots_mod_n]
    # print out all values in plain_candidates that are viable. For now 'viable' means
    # 'can be utf-8 decoded without error'
    for plain in plain_candidates:
        try:
            print(plain.to_bytes((plain.bit_length() + 7) // 8, 'big').decode('utf-8'))
        except UnicodeDecodeError:
            pass



def decrypt_example():
    n = 100730175368311633478971516550032530349548047538169668085371615323335993050104099450196588597255118857503982837564035479840164299648689097551903985734786810870973412764354972361685659545332423982337074709819705807204740343841119905746182935014914566332609661115911697020388848364957717731916021015186745684937
    p = 7929784484601571438556962301091075858855221082408119915984427404222889089508123170481994187868730450486555622247851839792346424851012282168291892181358521
    q = 12702763305095394050797091920448801436034799490575134387288377684776621453859015314357141487880257024105303175708994671153726639639927719205169291350500497
    e = 88
    c = 20105686147991941369013766839987314637794741418836048390207432144211428603343545341113483780787575674844374295850418357112562002976911845044695395223651780902249997312992203320108137212557982436701392702319743854706572541120465765715495541599418085021051751662008710898889028243528751455361486108662629587591
    decrypt((n, p, q, e, c))
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean you need to find flag? You've just read it from the file "flag.txt"!

Probably you want to find the decryption exponent "d" such that flag=pow(c,d,n), using your notation.

First you calculate Phi=(p-1)*(q-1) and then you find a matching "d" such that:

d*e=1 mod Phi, meaning that d*e divided by Phi gives the remainder of 1.

Just something worth mentioning is that your value of "e" is poorly chosen at "88" since it needs to be coprime with Phi and currently it's not. That doesn't mean the math won't work though, if it's just for your homework.

Comment: Thanks i do understand gcd(phi(n), e) != 1 , but given the output values of p q e c n I would like to find the value of flag which is not provided , the file is not present the question states it with the given output. Can you help on how to go about it?

Comment: I just told you in the answer above how to calculate flag=pow(c,d,n) where you calculate "d" as shown!

Comment: for d , i found (p-1) * (q-1) but if i do 1 mod this value , it returns as 1 for d, so where do i use e which is 88 and we see its not co prime?

Comment: (d*e) mod Phi = 1 is the formula to find d.

Comment: but how do i plug it in, to calculate d , i will have to do mod inverse then?

Comment: d = (1 % phi)// 88 will give answer as 0

Comment: Mate this modular arithmetic thing is really not that hard once you get the hang of it. For example you could take the brute force approach. Iterate through all "d" until you find one that multiplied with "e" and then divided by "Phi" will yield the remainder 1. You should find a solution rather quickly since there are many "d" that satisfy this property!

The text book approach would be to use the extended Euclidean algorithm to calculate "d". Basically it states that:

Phi*x+e*d=GCD(Phi,e), where GCD stands for Greatest Common Divisor. You can find an implementation for this on Wikipedia

Comment: I tried ```proots = GF(p)(cipher).nth_root(e, all=True)
qroots = GF(q)(cipher).nth_root(e, all=True)

for res in product(proots, qroots):
    m = crt(list(map(int, res)), [p, q])
    pt = int(m).to_bytes(m.nbits()//8+1, 'big')
    if b'flag_format' in pt:
        print(pt)``` in sage math but no luck, can you help me how to do about finding d and eventually finding value of flag

Comment: since 88 is not co prime so so d*e mod phi == 1 doesnt hold

Comment: I am not familiar with Sage but there are definitely many solutions to d * e mod phi = 1. Any of them should give you the value of flag.

Comment: i was not able to solve can you share what value of d worked since 88 is not co prime so so d*e mod phi == 1 doesnt hold  right?

Comment: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/12255/in-rsa-why-is-it-important-to-choose-e-so-that-it-is-coprime-to-%CF%86n

This article should shed some insight into e and Phi being coprime or not.

Comment: *...That doesn't mean the math won't work though...* Yes, it does mean that.

Comment: Can you help how to go about it please